# Can you call a method from an array element?

Tags: excel, perl, xlsx

I have the following code:

```
my $workbook  = Excel::Writer::XLSX->new( 'a_simple.xlsx' );
my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();
my @chart_performance1 = $workbook->add_chart( type => 'column', embedded => 1 );
my $no_of_titles = 3;

for ( my $no_of = 0; $no_of < $no_of_titles; $no_of++ ) {
    $chart_performance1[ $no_of ]->add_series(
        name       => $chart_heading[ 0 ],
        categories => [ 'Sheet1', $array_game_titles[ $no_of ] , $row_range_max , 0, 0 ],
        values     => [ 'Sheet1', $array_game_titles[ $no_of ] , $row_range_max , 1, 1 ],
    );
}
```

When I run it, I get the error:

```
Can't call method "add_series" on an undefined value
```

Why?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: can we call the module function "add_series" in this fashion.

Comment: @LohitRaj what happens when you tried? Read the documentaiton which has lots of examples.

Comment: /Can't call method "add_series" on an undefined value/ i'm getting this error @Dr.Avalanche

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got my Answer, Need to only declare the array instead of declaring and defining the array "chart_performance" with add_chart method at the same instance. As the add_chart method returns a single object i was getting the error. Thanks for the help BTW.

```
my $workbook  = Excel::Writer::XLSX->new( 'a_simple.xlsx' );
my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();
my @chart_performance;
my $no_of_titles = 3;

for ( my $no_of = 0; $no_of < $no_of_titles; $no_of++ ) {
    $chart_performance[ $no_of ] = $workbook->add_chart( type => 'column', embedded => 1);
    $chart_performance[ $no_of ]->add_series(
        name       => $chart_heading[ 0 ],
        categories => [ 'Sheet1', $array_row[ $no_of ], $array_col[ $no_of ], 0, 0 ],
        values     => [ 'Sheet1', $array_row[ $no_of ], $array_col[ $no_of ], 1, 1 ],
    );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This line

```
my @chart_performance1 = $workbook->add_chart( type => 'column', embedded => 1 );
```

looks wrong. The `add_chart` method returns a single `Excel::Writer::XLSX::Chart` object, so the result is normally assigned to a scalar, not an array. It's unclear what you're asking, but if you are trying to create one chart that plots three series of data, then you want something more like:

```
my $chart = $workbook->add_chart( type => 'column', embedded => 1 );
...
for ( my $no_of = 0; $no_of < $no_of_titles; $no_of++ ) {
    $chart->add_series( ... );
}
```

Comment: ya i was trying to assign the chart objects to an array to get different charts for 3 series of data for different titles.